# Can we use the WAR created using ANT in both Apache and Web Logic

Tags: deployment, weblogic, war

I have JAVA web application. And I wanted to automate the deployment process.
I am using ANT build tool for the build and deployment process. As of now we are deploying it in APACHE server. Can we use the same WAR file in the WEBLOGIC SERVER also?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since WL offers more functionality and not less (it's an application server after all), that should pose no problem.

Unless you use apache modules of course.